# Resolving Concrete Type in Class Library With Unity IOC

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I need to return an instance of a class from a class library method. However I do not have an instance of the Unity Container. So this does not work

```
container.Resolve<IMyInterface>();
```

How do I get an instance of the container from the parent application?

(Do I pass it to the class library or can I access it somehow?)

I have for example a startup project that calls a method in the class library

```
public MyClass(ILibrary data)
{
    IMyObject obj=data.GetStuff();        
}
```

And the following method in the class library

```
public IMyObject GetStuff()
{
   MyObject obj=new obj()
   obj.name="mystuff";
   return obj;
}
```

Comment: The container is not meant to be passed around. If the code is designed around dependency injection and the explicit dependency principle, it should not matter what container is used. The container is an implementation concern and should not be used as a service locator

Comment: So how do I create an instance of a class to pass back via a method in a different project?

Comment: You're going to have to provide some code to better explain your problem. But that aside you do not create an instance of anything, you register abstractions and their implementations with the composition root (container)  so when dependencies are requested the object graph can be resolved.

Comment: Ok so I have added an example of what I am trying to do. I obviously do not want to directly create an instance of the class (unless that is actually normal practice?)

Comment: Ok where is the problem? you register `MyClass`, `ILibrary` and its implementation with the container at the composition root of the application and dependencies will be injected when resolving `MyClass`.

Comment: That is not the issue. ILibrary is registered. The issue is with MyObject. I am having to create this directly. Is that not bad practice?

Comment: Register `MyClass` as well

Comment: My class does not need registering as it is called directly by the startup application. The issue is MyObject which I am having to instantiate directly in the class library as I can't resolve it because it has no knowledge of the Unity Container.

Comment: Is `MyObject` a service or model?

Comment: MyObject is a model

Comment: You create models. No need to register or resolve them.

Comment: Ok, That is great. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does that library "own" the container, or do you create the container and that library adds its configuration to it?